# How to make correct calculations?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a PostgreSQL database I have table called `answers`. This table stores information about how users answered a questions. There are only 4 question in the table. At the same time, the number of users who answered the questions can be dynamic and the user can answer only part of the questions.

Table `answers`:

```
| EMPLOYEE | QUESTION_ID | QUESTION_TEXT          | OPTION_ID | OPTION_TEXT  |
|----------|-------------|------------------------|-----------|--------------|
| Bob      | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1         | Yes          |
| Alex     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1         | Yes          |
| Kate     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 3         | I don't know |
| Bob      | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1         | Yes          |
| Alex     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 3         | I don't know |
| Oliver   | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1         | Yes          |
| Bob      | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 2         | No           |
| Alex     | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 1         | Yes          | 
| Jack     | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 2         | No           |
| Bob      | 4           | Do you like winter?    | 3         | I don't know |
| Alex     | 4           | Do you like winter?    | 1         | Yes          |
| Oliver   | 4           | Do you like winter?    | 3         | I don't know |
```

I need this result:

```
| EMPLOYEE | CALC |
|----------|------|
| Bob      | 2    |
| Alex     | 2    |
| Kate     | 1    |
| Jack     | 1    |
| Oliver   | 2    |
```

The `calc` column is calculated by the formula:

```
CALC = A + B;

A - If a user answered to first and/or second question then the value should be 1, otherwise 0.
B - If a user answered to third and/or fourth question then the value should be 1, otherwise 0.
```

For example Bob answered to all 4 question. For that's why calc column has value 2 for Bob. In the same time Kate answered only for first question. For that's why calc column has value 1 for Kate. In her case A is 1 and B is 0.

Right now I tried such code but it's work not as I expected:

```
select
    employee,
    (
        case when count(question_id = 1) or count(question_id = 2) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
        +
        case when count(question_id = 3) or count(question_id = 4) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
    ) as calc
from
    answers
group by
    employee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggravated function `SUM` distinct with `group by`.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT employee,
       (SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN QUESTION_ID IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN QUESTION_ID IN (3,4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) CALC 
FROM answers
GROUP BY employee
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7bb3e/6/0)**:

```
| employee | calc |
|----------|------|
|     Alex |    2 |
|      Bob |    2 |
|     Jack |    1 |
|     Kate |    1 |
|   Oliver |    2 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can I ask you one more question?! How to determine the number of users whose value of the `calm` column is 2? I have to wrap your code in subquery, which in my opinion is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to D-Shih's answer this could also be achieved by doing a count with a filter

```
select
    employee,
    (
        case
            when count(question_id) filter (where question_id in(1, 2)) > 0
            then 1
            else 0
        end +
        case
            when count(question_id) filter (where question_id in(3, 4)) > 0
            then 1
            else 0
        end
    ) as calc
from answers
group by employee
order by employee
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask you one more question?! How to determine the number of users whose value of the `calm` column is 2? Is there any way to make it without subquery, with more compact way?

Comment: What is the calm column? for what it's worth -> `select count(*) from "yourtable" where calm = 2`

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would phrase this as conditional aggregation, but not with `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
select employee,
       (max( (question_id in (1, 2))::int ) +
        max( (question_id in (3, 4))::int )
       ) as calc
from answers
group by employee;
```

In addition to being more concise, `count(distinct)` generally incurs more overhead than the more "basic" aggregation functions such as `min()`, `max()`, `count()` and `sum()`.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Can I ask you one more question?! How to determine the number of users whose value of the `calm` column is 2? Is there any way to make it without subquery, with more compact way?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.